# Angular 6 / Nginx / Docker / Kubernetes: configure environment variables for different environments

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, kubernetes, devops

I have an Angular 6 application that I'm required to deploy onto a Kubernetes cluster as a Docker container (Nginx Base Image). The same image is built once and used for dev test prod environments.Since the Docker image is created once and reused in other environments, we don't have the environment.ts file anymore.  I have env variables that i had to put in the index.html so each environment can have its setup. 
But it is not good because we can see some details, keys etc. 
Is there any other way or other architecture to avoid to put the env variables in the index.html ?
best regards

Answer (score 0):

It is usually good to have an endpoint on server which gets called during app initialisation, this way you won't hard code anything on client side which can be viewed by end user.

However, just having that won't be enough as you need to somehow protect them if stored on cache or local storage.

Comment: But the issue is between the image and containers at build time. I dont know how to build the containers with their own config.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, if you are exposing the value of any "environment variable" to your angular application it is therefore accessible by the end user.

To "transfer" the values of environment variables to your front-end I would modify your docker image and have a script run as your `ENTRYPOINT` that does the following:

1. `echo "var my_env_var = '$MY_ENV_VAR';" >> /usr/share/nginx/html/variables.js` (repeat for each variable)
2. Load the `variables.js` script in your angular application.
3. Start nginx in the foreground via `nginx -g 'daemon off;'`

Comment: Thanks @yomateo i will try that. Just one question about the point 3  : why do we have to start nginx in the foreground at the end with this command ?

Comment: @YoussefHarkati correct, since we are overriding the `ENTRYPOINT` we will need to start nginx ourselves.

Comment: thank @yomateo for the answer.   Do you think it is possible to load the variables.js  outside of the index.html of the angular app image ?